# Directory.GetFiles with '/' on any platform

Tags: c#, path-separator

I'm trying to get a path with `'/'` char using `Directory.GetFiles` or `Directory.GetDirectories` whitout replacing the string each time I produce one. I would simply ask the librairie to use `'/'` as the directory separator even if I have some Macro telling him to use AltSeperator on specific OS.

Comment: I think this is a string manipulation problem.

Comment: @Joshua I don't really see the problem, I should just be able to swap separator before to use the function and then get it back. Something as simple as that.

Comment: Until you have a \ in a filename (which is allowed on systems where \ isn't a separator).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately that doesn't seem to be possible.

`Path.DirectorySeparatorChar` and `Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar` depend on the OS your app is running on, and are read-only.

[According to the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.directoryseparatorchar?view=netframework-4.7.2) `DirectorySeparatorChar` is `\` on Windows and `/` everywhere else, and `Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar` is (currently) always `/`.

Comment: I really have a lot of sacrifices to do to use Unity I guess ^^" Thanks for your answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

General technique:

```
string MyPathCombine(string basename, string filename)
{
    int idx = basename.Length;
    if (idx == 0) return filename;
    if (basename[idx - 1] == '/') --idx;
    return filename;
}


IEnumerable<string> GetFilesSlash(string dirname)
    => Directory.GetFiles(dirname.Replace('/', Path.DirectorySeparatorCharacter)).Select((p) => MyPathCombine(dirname, Path.GetFileName(p));
```

If all your paths come from the real system, this simpler form would work, but if any come from another system, it will not as you could be poisoned by a `\` character. Not that this is the only hazard however. It gets bumpy from here.

```
IEnumerable<string> GetFilesSlash(string dirname)
    => Directory.GetFiles(dirname.Replace('/', Path.DirectorySeparatorCharacter)).Select((p) => p.Replace(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, '/'));
```

Comment: I would definitely prefer to have my own constant, with the value set according to the operating system.
Edit : I forgot I was using system functions, so yeah replacing is the solution I came by default. Not important enough to spend time on it. And it will probably be never satisfying anyway.